# Objective-C-Runtime Bug When Naming a Superclass "Message"

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I have the following class hierachy:

```
@interface Message : NSObject {}
@end

@implementation Message
- (void) dealloc
{
    // I won't be called
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

@interface FooMessage : Message {}
@end

@implementation FooMessage
- (void) dealloc
{
    // should call Message - dealloc
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

And the following unit test:

```
- (void) test
{
    FooMessage* msg = [[FooMessage alloc] init];
    [msg release];
}
```

The test will always fail with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. `FooMessage` calls it's super class destructor in `dealloc`, but the call never arrives there. Instead, the Objective-C runtime resolves the call to a different location:
[image: StackTrace and disassembly]

The error doesn't occur if the `Message` base class is renamed to something else, e.g. `AbstractMessage`. It appears there is another class named `Message`, whose definition is not publicly available.

Is this a bug? What's really happening here? Am I violating any naming restrictions (even though I think the compiler should warn me about that)?.

It's XCode 3.1. compiling for iPhone OS 3.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objectve-C lacks the concept of namespaces. The problem is well known and usually worked-around by using prefix-namespaces (like **NS**Object or **MK**MapView). You could name your message class `JrMessage` to avoid the clash with the (undocumented) class named `Message`.

The compiler could only warn you if it knew about the other class. In the case of private, undocumented classes, this often is not the case. The best way to handle this is to avoid clashes by using the prefix on every class. This also helps against future clashes, when Apple adds classes to a new release of the OS (which the compiler obviously couldn't warn about).

**Edit:**

Further investigation shows that the competing class origins from a private Framework named "MIME.framework", at least on the iPhone Simulator:

```
NSLog(@"Message class: %@", [[NSBundle bundleForClass:NSClassFromString(@"Message")] bundlePath]);

... Message class: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework
```

You might want to add this information in your [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: The unprefixed class is a bug in the system frameworks.   There may be a message on your console about the collision.  File a bug via http://bug reporter.apple.com/

Comment: @bbum: Are you aware of some place in the documentation where Apple gives a promise about class names?

Comment: @bbum Here's a late follow up to the same topic: https://github.com/NikolaiRuhe/UnprefixedFrameworkClasses