# App crashes when loading Data with NSKeyUnarchiver

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, loading, nskeyedarchiver

I save Accounts with the NSKeyArchiver to a file, but when I try to load them, my App just crashes saying that Account doesn't implement initWithCoder: even though it does and it also conforms to NSCoding:

```
-[Account initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa947a00
```

Account.m

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    _accessToken = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"accessToken"];
    _refreshToken = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"refreshToken"];
    _selected = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"selected"];
    lastUpdate = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lastUpdate"];
}
return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
[aCoder encodeObject:_name forKey:@"name"];
[aCoder encodeObject:_accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
[aCoder encodeObject:_refreshToken forKey:@"refreshToken"];
[aCoder encodeBool:_selected forKey:@"selected"];
[aCoder encodeObject:lastUpdate forKey:@"lastUpdate"];
}
```

AccountStore.m
And here I load them:

```
NSString *path = [[self archivePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"accounts.archive"];
accounts = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
if (!accounts) {
    accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Also I should mention that it already worked, but from one second to an other it didn't anymore. And I checked whether NSKeyedArchiver saved correctly: It does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be a name clash.

Apple's Message.framework contains a class named `Account`. While you would never link this private framework directly it could be loaded indirectly from other Apple frameworks, for example MessageUI.framework. I can imagine you recently added this framework to your project. This would be when your bug first occurred.

The only solution is to rename your `Account` class. There are actually [quite a lot of unprefixed classes](https://github.com/NikolaiRuhe/UnprefixedFrameworkClasses) in Apple's frameworks, so you [should use a name prefix](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002226-BBCJECED) anyway.

And you should file a bug, as proposed by @bbum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849965/104790).

Comment: yes, i think that is it. i added the framework and since then it didn't work anymore