# Why should I prefix my own classes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I get that Objective-C doesn't have namespaces and I definitely see the need to prefix class names in libraries and frameworks. But what would be the purpose of prefixing the class names in my own application?

Comment: So that they don't have name collisions with other classes, perhaps?

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I think this is a reasonable question from someone that wants to know more about something. It does not fit the criteria of a question to downvote (no research, not clear, not useful)

Comment: See https://github.com/NikolaiRuhe/UnprefixedFrameworkClasses

Comment: Nikolai's answer at [ObjC runtime bug when naming a superclass message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2849804) (linked from his link above) basically answers this: there may be badly-behaved framework classes that neither you nor the compiler know about.

Comment: Nikolai's link is actually the most convincing argument thus far. I would however consider it a bug (from Apple). Under normal circumstances it should never happen.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Right, so far the answer I have is to protect yourself from badly behaving frameworks. Still not convincing enough for me though to actually start prefixing my classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefixing reduces the likelihood of a collision. In an iOS program, this is not as likely because you know *most* of what you are loading. However, Apple could add some classes to the frameworks you load directly or indirectly, then you will have a problem.

The way it happens is that the runtime will load only one implementation when a collision occurs. So if you ask for a new instance you may be returned an instance of the other developer's implementation (=CATASTROPHE).

On OS X, you have much more opportunity to load dynamically. Conflicts do occur, and it's not so hard to run into them -- especially when you deal with plugins. So it's a great precaution, especially if your program will or may target OS X.

I consider it best (most safe and easy to migrate) to prefix, and is important to do so in both OS X and iOS. Even for the purpose of reusability and library development it's a good idea. 3 characters is the current recommendation for us, but 3 character prefixes can cause collisions. And if you incorporate other's libraries into your program, then there will be a chance you will have to rename a bunch of your classes -- if that library uses the same names as yours. These days, I tend to use double-prefixes, like *"ORG"* + *"Library"* or *"ORG"* + *"App"*.

Similarly, it's also a good idea to prefix any method names you add via objc categories.

Comment: As far as I know all of Apple's classes are prefixed, same for all 3rd party libs I've seen. Is it really realistic to say that there is a chance of collision? Adding a 3 letter prefix to all my classes really reduces readability, so I'd rather avoid it if the only benefit is theoretical.

Comment: @NickKeets they are not all prefixed. from Nikolai's link: *"in iOS 6.1 on an iPhone 5 there are 767 classes (of 10,307) that do not adhere to the naming rules."* -- can you name even half of the classes in either group? if so, you may be capable of using your knowledge to avoid collisions for specific existing OS releases where no 3rd party images are loaded. even prefixed names can collide in practice (not just theory). you have the reason to avoid them -- the risk is yours to take or work around. i won't tell you if readability is more important to you (I'm used to prefixes after 10 years).